# Unable to copy VLC skin to skins2 file

Tags: xubuntu, vlc

Way new to Xubuntu (installed it Monday), so I appreciate any help you can give me.

When I attempt to download a skin (Crux, in fact) directly to VLC's skins2 file, the download doesn't take place. When I download the same skin to the Downloads file, that works fine, but I can't then copy the file from Downloads to VLC's skins2 file. I've also tried to extract the information to the skins2 file from Downloads, but I get told that I don't have permission to do that.

I'm thinking that a) I have the wrong destination file somehow or b) that skin may not work with Xubuntu. How close am I?

Thanks in advance.

kiloseven, I'm not sure what you're looking for. The path I have for the skins2 file is:

/usr/share/vlc/skins2/

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Or, c) the skins2 folder of VLC is not available to you.  

ls -al /PATHTO/skins2 - replacing PATHTO with the real path to that directory - what does it show? Please edit your query above and paste the result in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal and run this:

```
sudo wget http://www1.videolan.org/vlc/skins2/crux.vlt
sudo cp crux.vlt /usr/share/vlc/skins2
```

Then open VLC and go to settings.
Under "look and feel", check the "use custom skin", and paste this in the "skin resource file":

```
/usr/share/vlc/skins2/crux.vlt
```

Then restart your vlc and you should be good to go.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

"I get told that I don't have permission to do that." I think you need to be root, therefore you need this command to do so `sudo su` then enter your password. Go to file CTRL+C then go to your destination CTRL+V. I'm assuming that you are not root according to your statement because you didn't mention something like that in your question "I was root user, and I copied the file however, it didn't work". 
 Second option : `sudo su` then `cd to your path where VLC should be` then `chmod +x the folder of skin under VLC`  after that you will be able to copy and paste any skin into your folder.

Thank you.